# Local Storage in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

i need help!

I am looking to uses chrome local storage in one of my apps. Basically this is supposed to be a shopping list app that store locally previously entered items as an object in JavaScript.

i must be doing something wrong because when there is nothing in local storage and i add an item i gets saved fine but then whenever i add a second item, the previous item gets replaced.

Here's my code so far

```
function useLocalStorage(shoppingListItem){

    let shoppingApp = {};
    
    if (localStorage.getItem(shoppingApp) === null){
       shoppingApp.shoppingList = [];
    }
    else {
       shoppingApp.shoppingList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('shoppingApp.shoppingList'));
    }

    shoppingApp.shoppingList.push({
      shoppingListItem : shoppingListItem,
      checked : false,
    });

    localStorage.setItem(shoppingApp.shoppingList.shoppingListItem, 
                         JSON.stringify(shoppingApp.shoppingList));
}
```

Comment: adding shopping list to storage is bad practice. use session

Comment: Are `shoppinApp`,  `shoppingApp` and `'shoppingApp.shoppingList'` meant to be equal or different?

Comment: sorry for the typo, i fixed it. shoppingApp is the containing object, shoppingList is a list property of that object and shoppingListItem is an item (object) in my shopping list

Comment: Keys must be strings, just like values. So the value passed to `getItem`, and the first argument to `setItem`, must be a string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

Answer (score 0):

Did you see how your localStorage looks like after executing the function?

If you did not do typos in code:

```
localStorage.setItem(
    shoppingApp.shoppingList.shoppingListItem, 
    JSON.stringify(shoppingApp.shoppingList)
);
```

The first argument will return `undefined`, you are trying to access proprty of `shoppingListItem` on `shoppingList` which is array. To get any value you need to access the item directly with for example `shoppingApp.shoppingList[0]`. Because of this error(?) for me it saves the list in `undefined` key.

```
let shoppingApp = {};

if (localStorage.getItem(shoppingApp) === null){
    shoppingApp.shoppingList = [];
}
```

This if statement is always `true`. What you are doing is trying to access item with key `{}` and because there is no key like that in your localStorage it returns `null` so your new shopping list is empty. You probably wanted to use here string: `if (localStorage.getItem('shoppingApp') === null)`. If you were to write the `{}` as a key so you could access it later - it would get parsed and the key would be "[object Object]" so I do not think that is your intended behaviour.